# If I want my `if` statement to work when I see the website, what should I do?

Tags: angular

I'm using this code in my template:

```
<mat-tab-group   mat-align-tabs="start"   (selectedTabChange)="onScrollDown($event)">
```

and this code is in my component:

```
  onScrollDown(evt:any ) {
    
    
   
      
    setTimeout(()=>{
         
        this.api.getApi().subscribe(({tool,beuty}) => {
          
            this.beu=beuty.slice(0,this.i+=15);
            this.tools=tool.slice(0,this .i+=15);
            
        })
     
        if (evt.index === 0) { console.log('ddd')};
            
    },1000);
   

  }
```

The problem is when I see the website the current `evt.index` is zero and the `if` statement does not work, it works when I change the tab and then go back to the first tab.

I think it is related to `selectedTabChange`.

If I want my `if` statement to work when I see the website what should I do?

Comment: "when I see the website"? Do you mean when you load the page the first time?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngOnInit`

Simple example:

```
export class FunnyClass implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() {
        if(whatever...)...
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Material tab group fires the event when the tab group changes, not when it loads.

It also sets `selectedIndex` only when a new index is selected. If `selectedIndex` is not set, it defaults to 0. If it is set, it uses it.

I don't agree with that behavior, I think selectedIndex should be set if it is not set, but that's how it is.

---

You can bind `selectedIndex` to a getter and setter. That way you can call other functions when it changes.

```
<mat-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]="selectedIndex">
  <mat-tab label="First">Content 0</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second">Content 1</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  _selectedIndex: number = 0;

  get selectedIndex(): number {
    return this._selectedIndex;
  }
  set selectedIndex(value: number) {
    if (value !== this._selectedIndex) {
      this._selectedIndex = value;
      
      // replace with if _selectedIndex === 0 or some function;
      console.log(this._selectedIndex);
    }
  }
}
```

You set `selectedIndex` in `ngOnInit()`, or load it back from some state or url.

```
...
export class AppComponent {
  ...
  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedIndex = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question requires re-formulation. The dots are just not connected.
In case you want to detect the tab change and manipulate your view based on activated tab, Angular Material has `MatTabChangeEvent` to detect the active tab in `MatTabGroup` and it is zero based. First tab has index 0.

```
onTabChange(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
    switch (event.index) {
      case 0:
        // your logic
        break
      case 1:
         // your logic
        break
      case 2:
        // your logic
        break
    }
  }
```